# Can we use a partial F test for logistic models?

Tags: logistic

I did sit an exam a few days ago and one of the questions went like: we have a logistic regression model with a bunch of regressors, one of them is catregorical and we want to test its significance, can we use a partial F test other than a G2? How would you answer?

Comment: What is a "partial F test other than a G2?"

Comment: @jbowman What I meant was that we can test significance using a G squared test, but is a partial F test valid as well? Our profssor explained G2 as the natural logarithm of the ratio between the likelihood of the full model and the likelihood of the reduced model.